# How to remove back entry from Navigation Stack in windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am migrating my windows phone 8 app to Windows 8.1 and my requirement is that I want to delete Navigation Back Entry, similar to Windows Phone 8. I was
achieving this using below line

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()
```

Please suggest what can be done in case of Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do that with the help of below code.

```
        this.Frame.BackStack.Remove(this.Frame.BackStack.LastOrDefault());
```

this code is to delete the last entry in the BackStack of Page navigation.

Additional information:-

The main difference here is, while navigating from one screen to another, the `Page` remains same, but navigation happens between `Frames`.

So whatever we used to work with `Page` in `windows-phone-8`, we need to act on `this.Frame`.

Comment: can you mention the error that you're getting by adding this

Comment: Do you know whether we can use Windows.Phone.Toolkit in Windows 8.1 App?

Comment: no, you can't use WP-toolkit in neither windows 8.1 nor in windows phone 8.1. b'coz wp-toolkit is for "Silverlight" platform whereas win 8.1 and wp 8.1 are WinRT platforms.

Comment: OK Thanks. Is there any control available similar to ListPicker of WPToolkit? I have used combobox but it sometimes doesn't meet my requirements.

Comment: `ComboBox` is the Best alternative for ListPicker of `WPTookit`. mention any of your specific scenario where your requirement meets in ListPicker but not in ComboBox.. even i would say `ComboBox` is an Extended control of `ListPicker`.

Comment: Add search box automatically and multiselect items  which was available in ListPicker but not in ComboBox

Comment: It seems like best match with your scenario is `ListView`. though you need to customize the `Style` of `ListView` control as you want, you can achieve what you want by it..